# UI5: How to use aggregation(average,sum) in OData version 2.0

Tags: odata, sapui5

I've an OData service version 2.0 `score>/MatchDetail` which has multiple scores. I want to calculate average score and show in my score tab instead of `72`. On page load, it should be calculated automatically. I didn't find any solution to calculate average or sum in OData version 2.0, secondly how I can use this service as well.

```
<!-- In score tab it should show the average. -->
<custom:coreTile topic="Average across all match" score="72" id="125252">
</custom:coreTile>
```

Comment: It's better to update to OData V4 implementation, it supports the $apply aggregation.

Comment: How large is the entity set from which you'd like to calculate? Would you mind calculating the average on the client side? Otherwise, I guess a custom query or function import is needed to let the backend do the job.